Internal error encountered on uploading audio file uri to gemini
Using Google Cloud to Upload Audio and Then Uploading the File to Gemini
Output:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

Request for Uploading Audio:
POST {} HTTP/1.1
Host: generativelanguage.googleapis.com
Content-Length: {}
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
X-Goog-Upload-Offset: 0
X-Goog-Upload-Command: upload,finalize

{:?}

Sending File URI to Gemini:
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "parts": [
        {"text": "What is the current Google stock price?"},
        {
          "file_data": {
            "mime_type": "audio/mpeg",
            "file_uri": "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/files/309oy4antidm"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Output:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

Fix the upload process for Gemini audio upload.
